# in magento 2 how can I redirect customer to bank payment url after placing the order?

Tags: magento2, payment

I am creating payment method module which requires external redirect to bank for user to verify funds withdraw. After user verifies purchase, bank will redirect it to my store's controller.

I want to use `redirectAfterPlaceOrder` but, url itself is obtained in backend `MyCompany\MyBank\Gateway\Http\Client\Client` object and accessible only after sending request to bank. This oject is a client, for my payment method, which is declared in `di.xml` :

```
   <virtualType name="MyBankAuthorizeCommand" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\GatewayCommand">
        <arguments>
            ...
            <argument name="client" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyBank\Gateway\Http\Client\Client</argument>
            ...
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

I tried to use `ResultFactory` to force redirect to bank url, but this was not successful. How can I redirect customer to banking url after placing the order ?